# Last one must have been too easy but this one should cover it

Tags: riddle, visual

A single word connects these images:

[image: An aircraft hanger]

[image: Some general waste]

[image: A pair of arms]

[image: A turn sign]

[image: A lemur tail]

[image: A medieval rack]

[image: Rain]

[image: A paint brush and paint cans]

[image: A science lab]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word might be:

> Coat

Because

> Hangar => coat *hanger*
>  
>  Waste => *waist*coat
>  
>  Arms => coat of *arms*
>  
>  Turn => *turn*coat
>  
>  Tail => *tail*coat
>  
>  Medieval rack => coat *rack*
>  
>  Rain => *rain*coat
>  
>  Paint => coat of *paint*
>  
>  Laboratory => *lab*coat

The title

> A coat *covers* surfaces.

Comment: Well done Norbo.  Correct answer, good explanations and interesting name... Norbo, welcome to puzzling!  (ps. the skeleton is on a medieval RACK)

Comment: @BrentHackers And how interesting this site is. Thanks for the warm welcome! :)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is:

> Black

Connections:

> Hangar -> Black Hangar Studios (film studio)
> Waste -> Blackwater (waste water)
> Arms -> Blackarm (cotton disease)
> Turn Back -> Turn Black? Black Turn: Operation Barbarossa?
> Lemur Tail -> Black Lemur
> Medieval Rack -> Black Death (during medieval period)
> Rain -> Black Rain (action thriller or music album)
> Paint -> Paint it Black (song)
> Science Lab -> Black Mesa (Half-Life series)

As for the title:

> When your eyes are covered, all you see is black.

Comment: Sorry.  It's nothing so dark.  Some good fits though.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers Damn. And there I thought I was onto something for once :(

Comment: and what an appropriate answer it would have been for you to get! :)